# IOS: React Native -> Code push (app-center ), changes does not reflect with react-native: "0.70.6" and "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.5"

Tags: ios, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

IOS: React Native -> Code push (app-center ), changes does not reflect with react-native: "0.70.6" and "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.5"

We are trying to deploy code via code-push. for android it looks fine now with some setting, but IOS build does not reflect new changes. Anyone can guide on this,

appcenter codepush release-react -a [USERNAME]/[APP] -d Staging -m --description 'test ' -t 2.0.0

[app center dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA08C.png)

We need to code push via app-center for ios build

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem my changes are not showing on iPhone. I am using below mentioned version in app.

react-native: "0.70.6"
react-native-code-push: "^7.0.5"

Changes are not reflecting on iPhone. Code is being pushed on appcenter but not downloading and install on iPhone devices.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).